# Are collisions in AES-128 theoretically possible when the plaintext is the same?

Tags: aes, symmetric, collision-resistance

Is it theoretically possible to find $P$, $K$, and $K^\prime$ such that $E_K(P) = E_{K^\prime}(P)$ where $E$ is AES-128 and $K \ne K^\prime$? I'd imagine this would be infeasible, but is it actually impossible?

Comment: I would not just say that is is possible, but highly probable, that there is a K and K' that result in the same ciphertext for some P

Comment: It should even be feasible to find one if you wanted bad enough. You would expect a collision search to require trying about $2^{64}$ keys with a single chosen plaintext. That is similar to the most computationally complex attacks that have been [carried out in practice](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/what-is-the-largest-performed-possible-bruteforce-attack-to-date).